# Do around 2 billion people eat insects regularly?

Tags: nutrition

Just listening to the radio, there was again the claim that two billion people eat (daily) regularly insects. After having lived in a few parts of this world, I do not believe that anymore.

Some sources for this claim: The Polish Ministry of Science and Higher Education [has a page](https://scienceinpoland.pap.pl/en/news/news%2C28495%2Cexpert-more-2-billion-people-worldwide-eat-insects-every-day.html) titled:

> Expert: More than 2 billion people worldwide eat insects every day

Some scientific citations go back to: FAO's ["Edible insects"](http://www.fao.org/3/i3253e/i3253e00.pdf) publication (which doesn't explain how they end up with that number). In its Executive Summary it says:

> It is estimated that insects form part of the traditional diets of at least 2 billion people.

In chapter 3 it's added that

> insect consumption is commonplace in the tropics, while in temperate zones it is often absent

So is it true or not? Sometimes people claim countries like Thailand, etc, but from my understanding people not originating from Isan province do not do that. This is 20 Million people (and my suspicion is, that in the wild 2 billion claim they just include the whole country). Also, e.g. in China, while sometimes insects are eaten, this is a rare occurrence, and not a source of protein. (You wouldn't count the worm in the tequila bottle, would you?)

Comment: Interesting list here ... https://www.businessinsider.com/bugs-as-food-around-the-world-2013-5

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks. I think at least half of it is fringe food (is this a word?); meaning only a few people in the country eat it and only on rare occations. Some seen to be actually new food (inspired by these 'we need to eat more bugs articles')

Comment: Do the crushed bugs used as dye in Starbucks coffee count?

Comment: The FAO claim is fairly different from the Polish expert one. "part of the traditional diet" doesn't really mean they still eat them at all, let alone regularly.  The latter (ch. 3) claim is alas not exactly quantitative.

Comment: @Fizz Yes.I believe the FAO article started the myth (but not sure). I searched for '2 billion eat insects' on google scholar, and you get a paper like "Insects as human food; from farm to fork" with "form an integral part of over 2 billion
people's diet". I looked at the citation and it is the FAO report.

Comment: [This Graphic from Ensia Shows How Entomophagy Can Be Nutritious and Beneficial](https://www.offgridweb.com/preparation/infographic-edible-insects/) Five billion people unknowingly consume 1 kg. per year.

Comment: @KeithMcClary: Ensia claims that 2 billion *regularly* insects but cites FAO, so I have some doubts...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beondegi Isn't Beondegi eaten many places? Available at Hmart in the US.

Comment: I'm in the U.S., and a coworker from Mexico used to bring [chapulines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapulines) to snack on at work.

Comment: @shoover Thanks. Can you ask him if this is a local food, or eaten all over Mexico (e.g. just like chicken) Wikipedia seems to claim that mosly Oaxaca region consumes this. I am not disputing people eat insects; just the number seems too high. If it were 200 Million I would say ok. If 500 Million, ok; from 1 billion: show me the breakdown.

Comment: @jwodder, actually it was used as red coloring in a strawberry smoothie, not in their actual coffee.

Comment: There is a vast gulf between "more than 2 billion people worldwide eat insects every day" and "insects form part of the traditional diets of at least 2 billion people". The former implies that eating insects forms a critical part of the diet of 2 billion people. The latter could include those who eat weird stuff on New Year's Eve for good luck throughout the upcoming year. Perhaps at the end of this year (31 Dec 2021) I should add insects to my New Year's Eve list of weird foods as I need a bit more good luck than I had (and the rest of the world has had) over the past year.

Comment: @DavidHammen From fao (the full book) as well "it is estimated
that insect-eating is practised regularly by at least 2 billion people worldwide". Yes, different claims are all over the place, probably you heard one or the other. To me the question would be, what it the best approximation of reality. (My suspicion: 2 billion people live in countries where some people eat insects regularyly). Also why am I asking: there are all these articles trying to encourage us to eat insects, and this claim wants to show it is 'not weird' but common. I doubt that.

Comment: I think it depends on what one calls "insects". The correct, scientific meaning refers to a very large group of animals, but there are several others that aren't "scientific insects" that we do still call insects on the day-to-day (like spiders, for example.) If one expands the term insect to refer to the entire group of arthropods, as to include spiders and scorpions, for example, then you would also include things like shrimp and lobsters, which are very common dishes all over the world!

Comment: @T.Sar For me it is all about the nudging 'billions of people eat insects, so should you' which you might have heard in the media. It is supposed to help people overcome their disgust, so question is do billions of people eat insects what people would call insects. Hey, if the claim would be: billion of people eat shrimp, eat more lobster, I would be totally fine with it.

Comment: Eating insects is not a bad thing, termites are almost pure protein. Anyone who has done any basic survival training will know that and BTW crickets / grasshoppers are both halaal and kosher while spiders are not.

Comment: Fried crickets are delicious, people in China, Korea and Japan eat it regularly. I guess it is close to 2 B of people.

Answer (score 7):

2 billion is far too low an estimate.

If you've ever eaten anything that contains red die (e.g. maraschino cherries, red candy, soft drinks, apple cider), unless the container is marked Vegan or Kosher, there's a good chance you were eating deliberately added insects. This can include products that say "natural color".

For more information, see: [Red Dye: A Moment in Science - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9YzM1Edb6mo&feature=emb_logo&ab_channel=NorthCarolinaMuseumofNaturalSciences)

#### NOTE:

I originally submitted this answer, perhaps deliberately misinterpreting the intent of the question, in order to present a possibly interesting but not well known fact.

I certainly didn't and don't think it's worthy of the bounty it received by virtue of being the only answer.

If someone ever submits an answer that the OP accepts, let me know and I'll offer a bounty and regift it to that answer.

Comment: I think the question is about eating insects as a main item and not as an addition to something else.

Comment: If you want to think about unknowingly eating insects as part of food there are actual limits to how many insects can be in it. https://www.greenqueen.com.hk/your-chocolate-bar-probably-contains-cockroach-parts-yes-its-true/

Comment: Why would "Kosher" matter?  According to Leviticus, it is allowed to eat locusts, crickets, and grasshoppers.  See https://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-21847517

Comment: The question is a bit vague, and cochineal was the first thing I thought of when I read it, but it says "More than 2 billion people worldwide eat insects every day", and I don't think you could show that that many eat it on a daily basis.

Comment: @GEdgar. A very small number of insect species are considered kosher.  But all other insects, in particular cochineal, are not.  My kosher comment referred to cochineal only.

Comment: Somebody please provide a (even) slightly better answer. I do not want to give the bounty to this one. Compared to this one even a list of countries where a non neglectable amount of people (lets say more than a million) are know to regularyly eat insects will get the 50.

Comment: @lalala, agreed. I wasn't expecting this to be the only one. Are you obliged to assign the bounty? If so, and there's nothing better by Sunday night, let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: @RayButterworth I think if I do not assign it, it gets auto assigned (just reading if at least two points https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). But actually if there is not better answer you can have it, no need to let points expire here. So do not delete your answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to [The psychology of eating insects: A cross-cultural comparison between Germany and China](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.foodqual.2015.04.013) *Food Quality and Preference* Volume 44, September 2015, Pages 148-156:

Based upon a survey conducted by this research,

67.7% of Chinese and 13.3% of Germans have consumed insects.

However, only 12.9% of Chinese and 0% of Germans consume insects "regularly".

Regarding Laos, according to [Insect Consumption to Address Undernutrition, a National Survey on the Prevalence of Insect Consumption among Adults and Vendors in Laos](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0136458)

> A total of 1025 (96.8%) lay people were currently insect consumers, 135 (13.0%) daily or weekly consumers, and 322 (31.1%) consumed several times per month. For the majority (575, 55.6%) the consumption was infrequent (less than a few times per year) and only 22 (2%) had never eaten insects.

Comment: https://www.ajol.info/index.php/ajfand/article/view/85317

Answer (score -1):

## Lets consider some of the OP's claims.

> insect consumption is commonplace in the tropics, while in temperate
> zones it is often absent

This just seems to be factually incorrect. Regardless of what you consider a 'temperate climate' insect have been consumed by many civilizations throughout mankind's history and in many climates.

[Entomophagy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entomophagy#Eating_insects_in_human_cultures) or the eating of insect among humans is not entirely bound to certain geographies.

> Indonesian botok tawon, spiced bee larvae steamed in banana leaf
> package Many cultures embrace the eating of insects. Edible insects
> have long been used by ethnic groups in
> Asia,[25][26][27][28][29][30][31] Africa, Mexico and South America as
> cheap and sustainable sources of protein. Up to 2,086 species are
> eaten by 3,071 ethnic groups in 130 countries.[9] The species include
> 235 butterflies and moths, 344 beetles, 313 ants, bees and wasps, 239
> grasshoppers, crickets and cockroaches, 39 termites, and 20
> dragonflies, as well as cicadas.[32] Insects are known to be eaten in
> 80 percent of the world's nations.[8]
>
> The leafcutter ant Atta laevigata is traditionally eaten in some
> regions of Colombia and northeast Brazil. In southern Africa, the
> widespread moth Gonimbrasia belina's large caterpillar, the mopani or
> mopane worm, is a source of food protein. In Australia, the witchetty
> grub is eaten by the indigenous population. The grubs of Hypoderma
> tarandi, a reindeer parasite, were part of the traditional diet of the
> Nunamiut people.[33] Udonga montana is a pentatomid bug that has
> periodic population outbreaks and is eaten in northeastern India.[34]
>
> Traditionally several ethnic groups in Indonesia are known to consume
> insects—especially grasshoppers, crickets, termites, the larvae of the
> sago palm weevil, and bee. In Java and Kalimantan, grasshoppers and
> crickets are usually lightly battered and deep fried in palm oil as a
> crispy kripik or rempeyek snack.[35] In Banyuwangi, East Java, there
> is a specialty botok called botok tawon (honeybee botok), which is
> beehives that contains bee larvae, being seasoned in spices and
> shredded coconut, wrapped inside a banana leaf package and
> steamed.[36] Dayak tribes of Kalimantan, also Moluccans and Papuan
> tribes in Eastern Indonesia, are known to consume ulat sagu (lit.
> 'sagoo caterpillar') or larvae of sago palm weevil. These protein-rich
> larvae are considered as a delicacy in Papua, eaten both roasted or
> uncooked.[37]
>
> In Thailand, certain insects are also consumed, especially in northern
> provinces. Traditional markets in Thailand often have stalls selling
> deep-fried grasshoppers, cricket (ching rit), bee larvae, silkworm
> (non mai), ant eggs (khai mot) and termites.[38][39]
>
> The use of insects as an ingredient in traditional foodstuffs in
> places such as Hidalgo in Mexico has been on a large enough scale to
> cause their populations to decline.[40]

[On the eating of locusts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locust#As_food)

> Locusts are edible insects. Several cultures throughout the world
> consume insects, and locusts are considered a delicacy and eaten in
> many African, Middle Eastern, and Asian countries. They have been used
> as food throughout history.[58]
>
> They can be cooked in many ways, but are often fried, smoked, or
> dried.[59] The Bible records that John the Baptist ate locusts and
> wild honey (Greek: ἀκρίδες καὶ μέλι ἄγριον, romanized: akrides kai
> meli agrion) while living in the wilderness.[60] Attempts have been
> made to explain the locusts as some ascetic vegetarian food such as
> carob beans, but the plain meaning of akrides is the insects.[61][62]
>
> The Torah, although disallowing the use of most insects as food,
> permits the consumption of certain locusts; specifically, the red, the
> yellow, the spotted grey, and the white are considered
> permissible.[63][64] In Islamic jurisprudence, eating locusts is
> considered halal.[65][64] The Islamic prophet, Muhammad, was reported
> to have eaten locusts during a military raid with his companions.[66]
>
> Locusts are eaten in the Arabian Peninsula, including Saudi
> Arabia,[67] where consumption of locusts spiked around Ramadan
> especially in the Al-Qassim Region in 2014, since many Saudis believe
> they are healthy to eat. The Saudi Ministry of Health warned that
> pesticides they used against the locusts made them unsafe.[68][69]
> Yemenis also consume locusts, and expressed discontent over
> governmental plans to use pesticides to control them.[70] ʻAbd
> al-Salâm Shabînî described a locust recipe from Morocco.[71] 19th
> century European travellers observed Arabs in Arabia, Egypt, and
> Morocco selling, cooking, and eating locusts.[72] They reported that
> in Egypt and Palestine locusts were consumed.[73] They reported that
> in Palestine, around the River Jordan, in Egypt, in Arabia, and in
> Morocco that Arabs ate locusts, while Syrian peasants did not eat
> locusts.
>
> In the Haouran region, Fellahs who were in poverty and suffered from
> famine ate locusts after removing the guts and head, while locusts
> were swallowed whole by Bedouins.[74] Syrians, Copts, Greeks,
> Armenians, and other Christians and Arabs themselves reported that in
> Arabia locusts were eaten frequently and one Arab described to a
> European traveler the different types of locusts which were favored as
> food by Arabs.[75][76] Persians use the Anti-Arab racial slur "Arabe
> malakh-khor" (Persian: عرب ملخ خور‎, literally Arab locust eater)
> against Arabs.[77][78][79]
>
> Locusts yield about five times more edible protein per unit of fodder
> than cattle, and produce lower levels of greenhouse gases in the
> process.[80] The feed conversion rate of orthopterans is 1.7
> kg/kg,[81] while for beef it is typically about 10 kg/kg.[82] The
> protein content in fresh weight is between 13–28 g / 100 g for adult
> locust, 14–18 g / 100 g for larvae, as compared to 19–26 g / 100 g for
> beef.[83][84] The calculated protein efficiency ratio is low, with
> 1.69 for locust protein compared to 2.5 for standard casein.[85] A serving of 100 g of desert locust provides 11.5 g of fat, 53.5% of
> which is unsaturated, and 286 mg of cholesterol.[85] Among the fatty
> acids, palmitoleic, oleic, and linolenic acids were found to be the
> most abundant. Varying amounts of potassium, sodium, phosphorus,
> calcium, magnesium, iron, and zinc were present.[85]

> Expert: More than 2 billion people worldwide eat insects every day

At the very least you could say that countries with at least 2 billion people in them consume insects. How often or how many they eat would be hard to estimate with any real amount of certainty.

> (You wouldn't count the worm in the tequila bottle, would you?)

Actually According to Anthony Dias Blue's Complete Book of Spirits, that "worm" is actually a larva from one of two types of moths, known as maguey worms, that live on the agave plant. These larvae are called gusano and bottles of mezcal that contain the creepy critters are referred to as con gusano.

A larvae of an insect is not a worm. The worm in tequila is not a worm at all and very much an infant insect.

[SOURCE](https://australian.museum/learn/species-identification/ask-an-expert/are-worms-insects-or-animals/#:%7E:text=No%2C%20worms%20are%20not%20insects.&text=Both%20worms%20and%20insects%20are,worms%20and%20insects%20are%20invertebrates.)
[SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maguey_worm)

Comment: Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/5) to support your claims.

Comment: "Expert: More than 2 billion people worldwide eat insects every day - This claim seems to be impossible to corroborate or refute." This is the core claim, and you fail to address it. Why would you say it is impossible to corroborate or refute?

Comment: The parts of this answer where you consider whether it is halal and kosher, whether they were eaten in biblical times, you opinions on whether insects are a "great" source of protein, and even whether the tequila worm is actually a worm are all irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I have made edits as per your requests.